# Rails, how to replace all 2+ white spaces with &nbsp?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

for my app if there is one white space that is fine. But if there is 2-4 I want to replace them with &nbsp to preserve the spacing.

What's the best way to do this with rails/regex? Or something else?

**Desired Output:**

```
' ' = ' '
'  ' = '&nbsp;&nbsp;'
'   ' = '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
'    ' = '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
```

Comment: should be fine if you replace single spaces with &nbsp - no?

Comment: @klochner - `&nbsp;` does not allow for a line break!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why do you need both of them converted? Why not leave one as an actual space?

Then you could just use a lookahead:

```
srt.gsub(/ (?= )/, '&nbsp;')
```

See it here in action: http://regexr.com?2vodu

Comment: It wont give expected output. `'  '.gsub(/ (?= )/, '&nbsp;') => '&nbsp; '

Comment: See the question, if 2 whitespace comes, both the space should be replaced with `&nbsp;`. but you code won't do that. you got?

Answer (score 6):

You just need a pattern that matches 2 or more spaces, then use the block form of `gsub` and look at how long the match is:

```
s.gsub(/ {2,}/) { '&nbsp;' * $&.length }
```

For example:

```
>> ' '.gsub(/ {2,}/) { '&nbsp;' * $&.length }
=> " "
>> (' ' * 2).gsub(/ {2,}/) { '&nbsp;' * $&.length }
=> "&nbsp;&nbsp;"
>> (' ' * 3).gsub(/ {2,}/) { '&nbsp;' * $&.length }
=> "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"
>> (' ' * 11).gsub(/ {2,}/) { '&nbsp;' * $&.length }
=> "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"
```